# Avoid duplicate group relation Many-To-Many [Doctrine2 - Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a method to find all discussions by array of users.

But I would like discussions with this exactly participants.

`User A`
`User B`
`User C`
are in `discussion 1`

and `User A` and `User D` are in `discussion 2`
`User B` and `User C` are in `discussion 3`

I would like only the `discussion 2` with the array participants `[User A, User D]` but I have discussion `1` and `2`

This is to avoid duplicate Discussion with same participant

```php
public function findDiscussionsWithThisParticipants(array $participants)
{
    $participantIds = array_map(function($o) { return $o->getId();}, $participants);

    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->andWhere(':participantIds MEMBER OF d.participants')
        ->setParameters(array('participantIds' => $participantIds))
    ;

    return $queryBuilder
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

There is no relation to `Discussion` on `User`.

```
class Discussion
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class)
     * @Groups({"discussion:write", "discussion:read"})
     */
    private $participants;
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between user and discussion entity?

Comment: Confused as to how your query is not throwing an exception, since `MEMBER OF` only accepts a single value and not an array of values and would result in `user_id = ?, ?`. The easiest option IMO would be to use an `->innerJoin('d.participants', 'p', 'WTIH', 'p.user = :user_1 AND p.user = :user_2')`, but would need more context from the association mapping of the entities.